# typescript error : tsc: command not found

Tags: typescript

Hello I just installed typescript and when i try to initialize tsc -v it gives me bash: `tsc: command not found error`.

When i was installing typescript with npm install `-g typescript@latest` it was installed with version 2.8.3.

My path is
/Users/ventzy/node-global/lib
├── eslint@4.19.1
└── typescript@2.8.3

As listed i can see it is installed but i can't call it in Visual Studio neither in terminal.

I am using MacOS 10.13.4 High Sierra.

So my question is how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to install it additionally locally by omitting the '-g' parameter?

Comment: In order to execute a version installed locally: `./node_modules/.bin/tsc -v`

Comment: DiabolicWords yes but that didn't help.

Comment: @Paleo When i try this it still gives me tsc:command not found. But in ./node_modules/.bin there is the tsc file.

Answer (score 0):

I Am using ‘npm ci’ to installment typescript which is part of devdependencies im my package.json 
Faded some issue. I have to add typescript to dependencies section also to make it work